# Log4j issue logging in same file from different application

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have 4 applications which configured to log in same file **opus-event.log** and all have following configuration.

I am facing issue is each application logging in original(opus-event.log) as well as backup file like opus-event.log2015-10-16 and event.log2015-10-17 on date 19 oct.

```
<appender name="event" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG"/>
        <param name="file" value="${jboss.server.log.dir}/opus-event.log"/>
        <param name="DatePattern" value="yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>
```

Please some one help me to know what issue it is ? is it possible to resolve using log4j configuration without changing log file name?

Answer (score 1):

You can't simply log into one file from 4 separate applications - there needs to be someone who manages and synchronizes the writes to the file.

Possible solutions:

- You can use multiple files (one for each application)
- If all applications are running in one JVM (e.g. application server), you might be able to configure them to use some shared logging service
- Send the log entries to a logging service - all 4 programs would send their logs to a logger application that would write them to file - see [Syslog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog) for inspiration